# Validation within a Symfony Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, validation, bundle

How do you implement the Symfony validator inside a bundle that *you* created?

I have an Extension class, a CompilerPass and a 'services.xml' file.

The validator is supposed to be injected in a middleware, and I tried in my Extension using:
`$container->registerForAutoConfiguration(ValidatorInterface::class)->addTag(...);`
but if I try finding the tag and dumping the key in my CompilerPass, then it claims I've requested an undefined service.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with your Extension class. You can inject the ValidatorInterface into the service where you need it. simply put it in the constructor with the type hint. `ValidatorInterface $validator`

Comment: Afaiui, bundles do not autoconfigure by default so at the very least you need to add some wiring in `services.xml`; I seem to have to working now by adding PHP configuration to the `framework` key in the `prepend()` method of the extension; I think otherwise the application needs to implement this? (and I am uncertain if its feasible to use a validator in the actual bundle that way...). Let me know if I'm wrong though (and see my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have something that validates, for example a messenger middleware:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace User\MyBundle\Middleware;

use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\MiddlewareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Middleware\StackInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Envelope;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

final class ValidationMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function handle(Envelope $envelope, StackInterface $stack): Envelope
    {
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($envelope->getMessage());

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            // exception
        }

        return $stack->next()->handle($envelope, $stack);
    }
}
```

and use `validator` as the id for the service injection configuration:

```xml
<!-- file: src/Resources/config/services.xml -->

    <service id="my.middleware.validator" class="User\MyBundle\Middleware\ValidatorMiddleware">
        <tag name="messenger.middleware" />
        <argument type="service" id="validator" />
    </service>
```

then configure the framework as you would in a normal application in your Extension class using the `PrependExtensionInterface`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace User\MyBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class UserMyExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // configure dependencies
    }

    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('framework', [
            'validation' => [
                'enabled' => true,
                'enable_annotations' => false,
                'mapping' => [
                    'paths' => [
                        __DIR__ . "/../Resources/config/validation/validator.xml",
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if we take a much more simpler approach. You can tell the user of your bundle to install your validation rules by adding a simple installation instruction in your readme file that tells the users to edit the `config/packages/validator.yaml`

```
auto_mapping:
        YourVendor\YourBundle\Entity\: []
    mapping:
        paths:
            - '%kernel.project_dir%/lib/src/YourBundle/Resources/config/validator.yaml'
```

The example shown above has the directory in the project directory. Which can be edited for convenience. In your `validator.yaml` file you can put your validation rules

```
YourVendor\YourBundle\Entity\Institution:
properties:
    email:
        - Email: { message: Please Enter a Valid Email Address }
constraints:
    - YourVendor\YourBundle\Validators\Institution\ClosingTime: ~
```